# About past tense/present in summary

Tags: past-tense

First, my teacher taught us to use present verb tense in a summary, but sometimes I just really want to use past tense.

for example (sociology essay,informal tho)

> A black female student is physically and verbally abuse by other students. Students bully her because she is academically advanced. Bullies call the victim’s racial names like “oreo” "white girl" and "wanna be white girl." Bullies try to push her down a flight of stairs, hit her with a bookbag, chip two of her teeth. Victim’s parents decide to remove her from the school and place her in home school because of things get so bad. Victim’s parents also inform district officials, but nothing change.

Victim’s parents **decide** to remove her from the school and place her in home school because of things **get** so bad.

Victim’s parents **decided** to remove her from the school and place her in home school because of things **got** (or gotten?) so bad.

Victim’s parents also **inform** district officials, but nothing **change**.
Victim’s parents also **informed** district officials, but nothing **changed**.

like it happened in the past (well for the first one   I kinda get it , because it happens after the bully,)
the second one, **changed**, I feel like it happened (after they informed them) like I'm just so confused

---

A Summary of “The Real Reason Why Highway Deaths Are Down” by Robert Reich

> In the article “The Real Reason Why Highway Deaths Are Down” the author, Reich, points out the real reason why highway deaths are down. The U.S. has a 3.9 percent drop in traffic fatalities since 2006. According to Reich, the real reason why highway deaths are down is the economy. Transportation Secretary Mary Peters credits the decline to safer vehicles. Reich argues that safer vehicles is not the reason, because the cars on our roads are basically the same. Some say that our roads are safer. Reich states that our roads did not abruptly improve, one major bridge even caved in. Reich concludes that economy is the real reason why highway deaths are down, because when the economy is going down, fewer people are on the roads due to high gas prices, another explanation is when unemployment rises, fewer people commute to work.
>   (this is the summary I wrote seriously)

Reich states that our roads **did not** abruptly improve (this is the one I want to use)
Reich states that our roads **are not** abruptly improve  (in present tense)

The first sentence, I feel like it is better, because it happened
The second sentence is just weird, like weird....

...one major bridge even **caved** in.
...one major bridge even **cave** in.

Wouldn't that be weird? since the bridge DID cave in.

Really need help with these. It has always been a problem for me about past/present tense.  (I am not asking for homework help, I already finished it, well...I don't know honestly, just have to give some example)

Comment: You are not summarizing a narrative there with the bullies, but writing a narrative.  Use past tense when writing a narrative.  Use present tense when summarizing a narrative someone else has written.

Comment: With the Reich essay, we refer to the essay or to the essayist using the present tense **Reich *states*** but we use normal past tenses when referring to past events that are cited in the essay, either **roads *did not improve*** or **roads *had not improved***.  The  past perfect in that context would signal reported speech.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is talking about the customary practice of using the present tense when summarizing someone else's text:

> In the movie *Star Wars*, we **open** with Princess Leia **chased** and **captured** by the evil Darth Vader.  Before she **is caught** two of her robots **escape** with the stolen Death Star plans, and **crash** on the planet below.  Eventually they **meet up** with Luke Skywalker and Ben Kenobi, who **recruit** the smugglers Han Solo and Chewbacca to help them **get** to the planet Alderaan to **deliver** the plans.

However, someone else's text can include past references, which you should not shift to the present tense

> In his essay, the author claims that Chamberlain **had** the best intentions when he **made** peace with Germany in 1937, since he **wanted** to avoid war as long as possible, but he severely **misjudged** the full scope of Hitler's military ambition.  However the author goes on to say that ...

It's common to mix various tenses in a single essay, depending on the time frame when they happen.  While this may be confusing at first, you should quickly become used to it, and automatically fit the pieces where they belong in time.

Comment: So for my Reich essay, I am using someone else's text which I should use past tense instead of present tense?

Comment: @JasonYi  You should use the present tense unless referring to statements where Reich himself uses the past tense, e.g. *"Reich **states** that the roads **did not** suddenly **improve**."*